# Why did the Enterprise go on her mission?

Tags: star-trek, uss-enterprise

My question is: Is there an *official* reason why the Enterprise went on their 5-year Mission? Or was it just to explore new worlds?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer from the intro is:

> Space: The final frontier. 
>   These are the voyages of the Starship, Enterprise. 
>   Its 5 year mission:
>   To explore strange new worlds.
>   To seek out new life and new civilizations.
>   To boldly go where no man has gone before.

That said, the Captain's logs add flavor and texture to the mission purpose throughout the series.